# Getting values from relationship attributes in Information Server

Tags: ibm-information-server

I am unable to get the values from Relationship Attributes using the method getAttributeValue().

I understand this function is the traditional way but are there any alternate methods or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

getAttributeValue() returs database ID of relationship item.
You can use functions below to work with a relationship attribute:

**getEntryRelationshipAttrib**

```
String[] Entry::getEntryRelationshipAttrib(String sAttribPath)
```

Given a relationship attribute path, returns an array of length 2 containing: [0]=Related Item's Catalog's Name, [1]=Related Item's Primary Key, for the related item. Exception will be thrown if attribute sAttribPath doesn't exist or it's not of relationship type

**getItemUsingEntryRelationshipAttrib**

```
Item Entry::getItemUsingEntryRelationshipAttrib(String sAttribPath)
```

return the related item object for given relationship attribute path. Exception will be thrown if attribute sAttribPath doesn't exist or it's not of relationship type